# How to configure rudder-agent?

Tags: configuration-management, rudder

When configuring rudder-agent, the doc says to fill policy_server.dat with the rudder-server hostname:

```
echo 'rudder-server' > /var/rudder/cfengine-community/policy_server.dat
```

Should i use preferably the fully qualified domain name (fqdn), or the short hostname of the rudder server ?

Answer (score 3):

Rudder agents will use the address you enter here to communicate with the server.

So you have to enter one that the agent can resolve.

The fqdn should work in any case.

Comment: If your DNS configuration is not fully working (can not reverse name), you might need to add the FQDN in yout /etc/hosts file, or even use IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

Rudder is flexible as to the hostname (or IP) you provide - it will simply run it through your machine's standard name resolution. Therefore, you *can* use whichever form is most convenient for you.

However, if you want to err on the side of safety, and you can trust your DNS system, prefer to use the FQDN. This will make sure Rudder can still contact it's server in case your local DNS configuration becomes broken (by, for example, a change in the default domain in /etc/resolv.conf).

If you can't trust your DNS system, prefer to use a hardcoded IP address here.